# Set a custom action bar..

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-actionbar, custom-action

I want to set a custom action bar i provide a image below..
this action bar i want to implement in android app and it should be completely customized ..How to set it to fragment or should i set using an activity ..i am little bit confused so please suggest me proper answer so i can do it properly..

[image]

Please Suggest me the answers so i can implement it in my app..

Comment: What is so tricky about it? Its just a normal `ToolBar`  with a `TextView` in center as title .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custum_background_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_height"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/button_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/button_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/button_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/custum_button_red_background"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/white">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/leftArrowContacts"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_keyboard_backspace_white_24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/anouncer_list"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_25sdp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/add_contacts"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: ty for gud ans.

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned in comments .

```
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/header_text"
                    android:text="Title"

                    />


            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Set the toolbar .

```
  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  TextView toolbarTitleTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
  getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
  toolbarTitleTxt.setText("Title")
```

And inflate a Menu for `MenuItems` and use `DrawerLayout` for drawer.